# How can I remove border in background image?

Tags: html, css

I have a background image on a `div`. It appears to have a small gray border around it that i don't desire for this site. I've tried to set the border & margin values to 0 but to no success. How can I remove this border?

[image]

CSS:

```
#back{
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 90%;
   bottom:0;
   background: url("back_i.png")no-repeat center center fixed; 
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="head">
       <ul>
            <li id="home">Home</li>
            <li id="about">About</li>
            <li id="audio">Audio</li>
            <li id="contact">Contact</li>
       </ul>
 </div>
 <div id="back">
       <div id="content">
                 //
       </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Paste your complete code in jsfiddle or try something like `background-position: -1px` `margin-top: -1px` etc or crop that image.

Comment: You could edit/crop the image maybe?

Comment: the border doesn't appear on the image. i'm not sure why the border is showing but i've mamaged to solve it using: `background-size: 101% 101%;` thanks to @Mardzis comment

Comment: Well, without the full markup and css we cannot help. If there is a border, then we need the markup to look where it comes from.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough credits so couldn't comment but even I would have suggested`background-position: -1px` `margin-top: -5px` and I am sure it would work without re-sizing your background image. However, when I first came across this concept of negative margin, I did some reading. Hope it helps.

The laws of the screen and desktop icons and the visible screen layout and the necessary actions that we can perform like **click drag drop** etc are governed by the Fitts's Law.
According to the Fitts's Law the edges of a visible screen is called as infinity (if you push your mouse in any direction the pointer will stop at the edge and so relatively infinite) in the same analogy a part of the screen which is not visible is termed as negative, and the screen available is positive. So, a negative value or margin means to pull the element in that direction beyond the visible screen frame.

[Fitts' Law] (https://www.interaction-design.org/encyclopedia/fitts_law.html)